# Word-wrap not working in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a button having some text over it. But the text is not wrapping on the button. Here is what i have done.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <input type="radio" id="1" class="hidden">
    <label for="1" class="btn btn-info btn-preference  pull-right">Stability</label> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <input type="radio" id="1" class="hidden">
    <label for="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-preference text-center">
      <span class="break-wo">Freedom and Risk</span>                                                        
    </label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Link for bootfly](http://bootply.com/108256)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not the wrap, it's `white-space: nowrap;` which is preventing the text to wrap when used `.btn` which contains `white-space: nowrap;` so use `white-space: normal;`

```
label[for="1"].btn {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://bootply.com/108258)

---

Note: Your `ID` value is invalid, you cannot start an `id` with a number

Comment: Mr. Alien Magic again

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, i will mark it as answer once the site allow me.

Comment: +1. By the way, why does Bootstrap "like" using `white-space: nowrap;` property? I think this goes against the principle of responsiveness. I would like to understand the logic: for example, when I want to create responsive tables, the Bootstrap documentation suggests wrapping the `<table>` with an element which is supplied with the `table-responsive` class (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive). In this case, `nowrap` property is used, which results in not being able to see the cell's whole text when viewing the page on a phone (only if I can scroll).

Comment: With `white-space: normal;`, text will wrap when necessary, which makes it more "responsive" in my opinion. Examples: 1st case: http://www.bootply.com/render/BtzTkf1jcn (and the result (on a Samsung Galaxy S Advance, Android's built-in browser): http://i.imgur.com/CXhvaCQ.png), 2nd case: http://www.bootply.com/render/b55Sy7gfTz (and the result: http://i.imgur.com/VCbUl5z.png). How is the latter (using `nowrap`) "responsive" when the text will never wrap to the next line?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `white-space: normal;` to your `span class="break-wo"`? This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
<div class="radio">
 <label class="btn btn-info">
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="optionsRadios" class="hidden" value="option1" checked>
  Option one
 </label>
</div>
```

Adding the  tag inside the label