# Word-Wrap on long words not working in bootstrap fluid containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I have been using bootstrap to make my page mobile friendly. My content is dynamically generated, so if someone puts a very long text (like lorem ipsum) it okay since i have a truncate, but i'm having problems with long words.

Heres the actual situation: [Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03fOZ.png)

And this is how i wish it would look like: [Intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOESk.png)

I've tried the following solutions to no avail:

- [bootstrap 3 wrap text content within div for horizontal alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641913/bootstrap-3-wrap-text-content-within-div-for-horizontal-alignment)
- [Word-wrap not working in bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331988/word-wrap-not-working-in-bootstrap-3)
- [Twitter Bootstrap Button Text Word Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996202/twitter-bootstrap-button-text-word-wrap)

I'm Using Bootstrap 3.3.2, Twig and Symfony. Here's the code

```
<tr class="row">
<td class="col-sm-12 clickable" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{pregunta.id}}">
    <div style="height:150px;overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;">
        {{ pregunta.contenido|markdown|raw|truncate(150) }}
    </div>
</td>
```

And here is how its being rendered:

```
<tr class="row">
<td class="col-sm-12 clickable" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-4">
    <div style="height:150px;overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;">
        <p>PreguntaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaLargaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaioooooooooooo</p>

    </div>
</td>
```

i've also added the property

```
p{
word-wrap: break-word;}
```

To my css, and if i inspect the paragraph, it has it, also added the white-space: normal; and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a width on the element, it should wrap itself without needing anything else. Have you tried that? Also i think word-wrap only works if you specify the width

Comment: I cant specify a width, or it'll look good either on Mobiles or on desktops, not both. In other words i'd lose the bootstrap fluid containers

Comment: How about setting max-width on p element ?

Comment: Same situation as before, if i set a max width (for example) of 100px, it would look good on mobiles but not on desktops. If i set a larger max width , it would be the opposite